# Euler 75 what is wrong, I have all primitive triangles and multiples but still something fails

Tags: haskell, pythagorean

- Basetri looks just like the wikipedia definition of the euclidian
  algorithm (but i only save perimeter) , and seems to generate all
  triangles.
- Timesify gives all multiples of these triangles (the 120 triangle
  appears 3 times)
- Then i concatenate, sort and group to give list of lists with each of
  the perimeters in same group, then filter the ones with more than 1
  just one way to make the perimeter.

This should give me all the triangles that are just possible to do in just one way, however  `length euler75 = 157730` does not seem to be the valid answer.

```
euler75 = filter justOneElement $ group $ sort $ concat $ timesify (takeWhile (<=1500000) basetri)

justOneElement (x:[]) = True
justOneElement _ = False

basetri = [((x m n + y m n + z m n)) | m<-[1..700],n<-[1..(m-1)], odd (m-n),gcd m n == 1]
    where
        x m n = (m^2 - n^2)
        y m n = 2*m*n
        z m n = (m^2+n^2)

timesify [] = []
timesify (x:xs) = (takeWhile (<=1500000) $ (map (*x) [1..])) : timesify xs
```

Comment: Are you putting "length euler75 = 157730" as the answer? Because I think you are just supposed to put in "157730".

Comment: accidentally working on same problem :) +1

Comment: @DamienBlack: only "157730"

Answer (score 1):

Changed to

```
triangs :: Integer -> [Integer]
triangs l = [p | n <- [2..1000],
               m <- [1..n-1],
               gcd m n == 1,
               odd (m+n),
               let p = 2 * (n^2 + m*n),
               p <= l]
```

and now it works